# 5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition: AND TypeError: Error #1006: hitTestObject is not a function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have 2 issues in this code.
The first is:
5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition: Sprayer, bugs

I've put multiple Actionscripts together to create this, i've seperated out the classes and am hoping to play this on a frame from a symbol.

and the second relates to:
Error #1006: hitTestObject is not a function

For this i'm trying to get the aagun/Sprayer to lose health then lives if the bugs touch it, but i'm not sure why it's saying it's not a function. Am I using the wrong words?

Thanks for your help, here's the code

```
package Shooter{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.getTimer;

class Sprayer extends MovieClip{
    const speed:Number = 150.0;
    var lastTime:int; // animation time

    function Sprayer() {
        // initial location of gun
        this.x = 275;
        this.y = 340;

        // movement
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveGun);
    }

    function moveGun(event:Event) {
        // get time difference
        var timePassed:int = getTimer()-lastTime;
        lastTime += timePassed;

        // current position
        var newx = this.x;

        // move to the left
        if (MovieClip(parent).leftArrow) {
            newx -= speed*timePassed/1000;
        }

        // move to the right
        if (MovieClip(parent).rightArrow) {
            newx += speed*timePassed/1000;
        }

        // check boundaries
        if (newx < 10) newx = 10;
        if (newx > 540) newx = 540;

        // reposition
        this.x = newx;
    }

    // remove from screen and remove events
    function deleteGun() {
        parent.removeChild(this);
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveGun);
    }
}
}

package BigBug{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

    class bugs extends MovieClip {
    var dx:Number; // speed and direction
    var lastTime:int; // animation time

    function bugs(side:String, speed:Number, altitude:Number) {

        if (side == "left") {
            this.x = -50; // start to the left
            dx = speed; // fly left to right
            this.scaleX = 1; // reverse
        } else if (side == "right") {
            this.x = -50; // start to the right
            dx = -speed; // fly right to left
            this.scaleX = 1; // not reverse
        }
        this.y = altitude; // vertical position

        // choose a random plane
        this.gotoAndStop(Math.floor(Math.random()*4+1));

        // set up animation
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,movePlane);
        lastTime = getTimer();
    }

    function movePlane(event:Event) {
        // get time passed
        var timePassed:int = getTimer()-lastTime;
        lastTime += timePassed;

        // move plane
        this.x += dx*timePassed/2000;

        // check to see if off screen
        if ((dx < 0) && (x < -50)) {
            deletePlane();
        } else if ((dx > 0) && (x > 350)) {
            deletePlane();
        }

    }
    }
}





package Missiles{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

class Bullets extends MovieClip {
        var dx:Number; // vertical speed
        var lastTime:int;

function Bullets(x,y:Number, speed: Number) {

    // set start position
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    // get speed
    dx = speed;
    // set up animation
    lastTime = getTimer();
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveBullet);
}

 function moveBullet(event:Event) {
  // get time passed
    var timePassed:int = getTimer()-lastTime;
    lastTime += timePassed;

    // move bullet
    this.x += dx*timePassed/1000;

    // bullet past top of screen
    if (this.x < 0) {
        deleteBullet();
    }

}

// delete bullet from stage and plane list
 function deleteBullet() {
    MovieClip(parent).removeBullet(this);
    parent.removeChild(this);
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,moveBullet);
}
}
}






package MainGame{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import Missiles.Bullets;
import Shooter.Sprayer;
import BigBug.bugs;

public class AirRaid extends MovieClip {
    private var aagun:Sprayer;
    private var airplanes:Array;
    private var buggood:Array;
    private var bullets:Array;
    public var leftArrow, rightArrow:Boolean;
    private var nextGbug:Timer;
    private var nextPlane:Timer;
    private var shotsLeft:int;
    private var shotsHit:int;

    public function startAirRaid() {
        // init score
        shotsLeft = 20;
        shotsHit = 0;
        showGameScore();

        // create gun
        aagun = new Sprayer();
        addChild(aagun);

        // create object arrays
        buggood = new Array();
        airplanes = new Array();
        bullets = new Array();

        // listen for keyboard
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownFunction);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUpFunction);

        // look for collisions
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkForHits);

        // start planes flying
        setNextPlane();
        setNextGbug();
    }

    public function setNextPlane() {
        nextPlane = new Timer(1000+Math.random()*1000,1);
        nextPlane.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,newPlane);
        nextPlane.start();
    }

    public function newPlane(event:TimerEvent) {
        // random side, speed and altitude
        if (Math.random() > .5) {
            var side:String = "left";
        } else {
            side = "right";
        }
        var altitude:Number = Math.random()*50+20;
        var speed:Number = Math.random()*150+150;

        // create plane
        var p:bugs = new bugs(side,speed,altitude);
        addChild(p);
        airplanes.push(p);

        // set time for next plane
        setNextPlane();
    }


    public function setNextGbug() {
        nextGbug = new Timer(1000+Math.random()*1000,1);
        nextGbug.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,newGbug);
        nextGbug.start();
    }

    public function newGbug(event:TimerEvent) {
        // random side, speed and altitude
        if (Math.random() > .5) {
            var side:String = "left";
        } else {
            side = "right";
        }
        var altitude:Number = Math.random()*50+20;
        var speed:Number = Math.random()*150+150;

        // create Gbug
        var p:Good_bug = new Good_bug(side,speed,altitude);
        addChild(p);
        buggood.push(p);

        // set time for next Gbug
        setNextGbug();
    }





    // check for collisions
    public function checkForHits(event:Event) {
        for(var bulletNum:int=bullets.length-1;bulletNum>=0;bulletNum--){ 
            for (var airplaneNum:int=airplanes.length-1;airplaneNum>=0;airplaneNum--) {
                if (bullets[bulletNum].hitTestObject(airplanes[airplaneNum])) {
                    airplanes[airplaneNum].planeHit();
                    bullets[bulletNum].deleteBullet();
                    shotsHit++;
                    showGameScore();
                    break;
                }
            }
for(var bulletNum:int=bullets.length-1;bulletNum>=0;bulletNum--){ 
            for (var Good_bugNum:int=buggood.length-1;Good_bugNum>=0;Good_bugNum--) {
                if (bullets[bulletNum].hitTestObject(buggood[Good_bugNum])) {
                    buggood[Good_bugNum].GbugHit();
                    bullets[bulletNum].deleteBullet();
                    shotsHit--;
                    showGameScore();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if ((shotsLeft == 0) && (bullets.length == 0)) {
            endGame();
        }

        }

        if ((shotsLeft == 0) && (bullets.length == 0)) {
            endGame();
        }
    }

    // key pressed
    public function keyDownFunction(event:KeyboardEvent) {
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
            leftArrow = true;
        } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
            rightArrow = true;
        } else if (event.keyCode == 32) {
            fireBullet();
        }
    }

    // key lifted
    public function keyUpFunction(event:KeyboardEvent) {
        if (event.keyCode == 37) {
            leftArrow = false;
        } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
            rightArrow = false;
        }
    }

    // new bullet created
    public function fireBullet() {
        if (shotsLeft <= 0) return;
        var b:Bullets = new Bullets(aagun.x,aagun.y,-300);
        addChild(b);
        bullets.push(b);
        shotsLeft--;
        showGameScore();
    }

    public function showGameScore() {
        showScore.text = String("Score: "+shotsHit);
        showShots.text = String("Shots Left: "+shotsLeft);
    }

    // take a plane from the array
    public function removePlane(plane:bugs) {
        for(var i in airplanes) {
            if (airplanes[i] == plane) {
                airplanes.splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    // take a Gbug from the array
    public function removeGbug(Gbug:Good_bug) {
        for(var i in buggood) {
            if (buggood[i] == Gbug) {
                buggood.splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    // take a bullet from the array
    public function removeBullet(bullet:Bullets) {
        for(var i in bullets) {
            if (bullets[i] == bullet) {
                bullets.splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // game is over, clear movie clips
    public function endGame() {
        // remove planes
        for(var i:int=airplanes.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            airplanes[i].deletePlane();
        }
        for(var i:int=buggood.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
            buggood[i].deleteGbug();
        }
        airplanes = null;
        buggood = null;
        aagun.deleteGun();
        aagun = null;

        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownFunction);
        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUpFunction);
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,checkForHits);

        nextPlane.stop();
        nextPlane = null;
        nextGbug.stop();
        nextGbug = null;


        gotoAndStop("gameover");
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.

> 5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition: Sprayer, bugs

As it says exactly: you can't have more than one public definition in a file. You have to either split the code to several files or move definitions, that you don't need public, out of the package.

This would be Ok in one file:

```
package  
{   
    import flash.display.MovieClip; 
    // public is the default access modifier
    public class Test1 extends MovieClip 
    {   
        public function Test1() 
        {
            trace("test1");
            var t2:Test2 = new Test2();
            var t3:Test3 = new Test3();
        }
    }   
}

// Test2 and Test3 are defined outside of the package, otherwise it wouldn't compile.
// These definitions will only be visible to code in this file.

import flash.display.MovieClip;
class Test2 extends MovieClip 
{   
    public function Test2() 
    {
        trace("test2");
    }
}   

class Test3 extends MovieClip 
{   
    public function Test3() 
    {
        trace("test3");
    }
}
```

2.

> Error #1006: hitTestObject is not a function

This usually means that `hitTestObject()` is not defined on the object (or it's ancestors) you are trying to call it from (although there could be different kinds of errors for that).

`hitTestObject()` is accessed in two ways in your code: `airplanes.hitTestObject()` and `bullets[bulletNum].hitTestObject()`. You will have to debug your code to see what is actually `airplanes` and `bullets[bulletNum]`, what types they are and whether they inherit `hitTestObject()` method. You could at least `trace()` them.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the update.. I've changed the above code...  I've tried to look at 5006: An ActionScript error with your comments and some research, but i'm still getting the error. Now it says 5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition: Shooter.Sprayer, BigBug.bugs"                                                                                  Can you let me know if you can see what i'm missing?

Comment: When you declare a `package`, you normally want something in it to be visible to the outside code. If you declare a class inside a package, it automatically becomes accessible from outside, thus stopping you from putting any other classes into the same file. You either move other classes OUTSIDE any packages, as I show in my answer, or you move the declarations to separate files. Putting classes into separate packages in one file doesn't help. There is no particular workaround, because there is no problem actually. What stops you from using several files, I wonder?